# How to remove caption p class from wordpress?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, wordpress

I don't want any images or their captions to appear within my loop, but I want to maintain the styling of the html.

So far I'm able to rid myself of the images using this function:

```
function remove_images () {
$content = get_the_content();
$content = apply_filters('the_content', $content);
$content = strip_tags($content, '<p><a>');
return $content;
}
```

Now, since I've kept all `<p>` tags for styling purposes and to keep written article content, this means the captions for the images are not removed because they're wrapped in `<p class="wp-caption-text">`

So now, how can I remove just that one class so that the captions don't appear? And I want to write it as a function to call it at specific times. I have multiple loops and in some of them I want the captions and in others I don't...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, rather than the way you're doing this I would use `the_content()` where you want the content outputted (in your template or wherever you're using this). Then, use `add_filter()` to modify the content.

Secondly to remove the tag with a class you'll have to use our good old friend regex. So your code might look a bit like this:

```
function remove_images( $content ){
    if( /*condition for where you want this to occur*/ ){
        $content = strip_tags($content, '<p><a>');
        $content = preg_replace('#<p class="wp-caption-text">(.*?)</p>#', '', $content );
    }
    return $content;
}
add_filter( 'the_content', 'remove_images', 100, 1);
```

Comment: Okay, so I've put this function in functions.php and made the if conditional this: `is_page_template(get_template_directory_uri() . 'templates/slider-with-text.php')` Then on the template page I'm not sure what I'm supposed to do. I've tried just `the_content()` but the images and caps appear. I've tried `remove_images(the_content())` with same result. I tried `remove_images($content)` and get an error of undefined `$content`. Sorry, I'm just not sure how to call this function on the template page or to test if my conditional directed at that template is even accurate. I appreciate your help

Comment: `functions.php` is the correct location for the `remove_images()` function and `add_filter`. Then in the template simply using `the_content()` is correct. If you check out `the_content()` you'll see there is an `apply_filters()` function. This is where any changes made by `add_filter()` functions are applied.

Comment: You can test whether the if statement is the problem by removing the if statement and just executing the code within. If it works you need to change your if statement condition.

Comment: Try this as the condition in your if statement `is_page_template( 'templates/slider-with-text.php' )`. The function should know you're looking in the theme directory already.

Comment: Yes, the problem was the if statement. Thank you very much. I changed it to `is_page_template( 'templates/slider-with-text.php' ` and now it works perfectly. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

You can use jquery removeClass function to remove that particular class

You can use it something like this:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $("p.wp-caption-text").removeClass("wp-caption-text");
});
```

You can learn more about removeclass from [here](https://api.jquery.com/removeclass/)